# Nginx URL rewrite storing part of URI & Using it in redirect

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

Trying to make a nginx url rewrite for a branding only global site that
 has search functionality (but no product catalog assigned as it's the global site) that will store part(or all if it's better) of the URL to pass it to a dedicated redirect script that geo redirects the user's query to the correct regional site.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with what I am doing?

```
rewrite ^/catalogsearch/result?q=(.*)$ 
        /redirect-script?x=/catalogsearch/result=q=$1 
        permanent;
```

Comment: are you sure you want to rewrite and not redirect? the scrip name and flag suggest otherwise.

Comment: What do you want, rewrite or redirect? Your sample is redirect, while you write about rewrite

Comment: I would like to 301 to a redirect script if that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can match the query string with the rewrite regexp.

Try this:

```
rewrite ^/catalogsearch/result$ 
        /redirect-script?x=/catalogsearch/result=q=$arg_q 
        permanent;
```

`$arg_q` is one of the automatic variables containing the query arguments, see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_arg_